# Ember fixtures and hasMany relations

Tags: javascript, ember.js

For some reason the code below results in `Error while loading route: TypeError: Cannot read property 'typeKey' of undefined`.  Everything loads fine until I add the **comments** in the Note fixtures.  I assume that having the comments nested in the note fixtures would work seeing as that is the way the API would return it, but that seems to be the break point.

** I should note that I have tried to add fixtures to the comments model and with a note_id referencing back to a note.  I don't get an error, but I don't get any replies showing up**

Thanks for any help.

#### models/note.js

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

var Note = DS.Model.extend({
  content:  DS.attr('string'),
  comments: DS.hasMany('comment'),
});

Note.reopenClass({
  FIXTURES: [
    {
      id: 1,
      content: 'This is the first comment',
      comments: [
        { id: 1, content: 'First comment' },
        { id: 2, content: 'Second comment' },
        { id: 3, content: 'Third comment' }
      ]
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      content: 'This is the second comment',
      comments: [
        { id: 4, content: 'First comment' },
        { id: 5, content: 'Second comment' },
        { id: 6, content: 'Third comment' }
      ]
    }
  ]
});

export default Note;
```

#### templates/notes.hbs

```
{{#each}}
<div>
  <div>{{content}}</div>

  {{#each comments}}
  {{this.content}}
  {{/each}}
</div>
{{/each}}
```

#### models/comment.js

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

var Comment = DS.Model.extend({
  content:   DS.attr('string'),
  timestamp: DS.attr('date'),

  note: DS.belongsTo('note')
});

Comment.reopenClass({
  FIXTURES: [
    { id: 1, content: 'First comment',  note_id: 1 },
    { id: 2, content: 'Second comment', note_id: 1 },
    { id: 3, content: 'Third comment',  note_id: 1 }
  ]
});

export default Comment;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like I was missing a couple things.

need the *async* options in the relationships set to true

```
comments: DS.hasMany('comment', { async: true })
```

needed to set a relationship in the parent to the children

```
Note.reopenClass({
  FIXTURES: [
    {
      id: 1,
      content: 'This is the first comment',
      comments: [1, 2, 3]
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      content: 'This is the second comment',
      comments: [4, 5, 6]
    }
  ]
});
```